# Apply logical AND to a list of boolean values

Tags: kotlin, fold

Consider a mutable list with boolean values,

```
MutableList{true, false, false}
```

How to return the boolean value after performing a logical AND on all of the values within the list using Kotlin fold?

Comment: are you specifically looking to use fold ?why not just check if the list contains at least one false ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the list is not empty, if any item of the list is `false` then the result is `false`:

```
val result = !list.any { !it }
```

Comment: Using `list.all {it}` is cleaner as it doesn't require the negations

Answer (score 8):

This is a common case for fold operator, you mentioned.

```
val list = mutableListOf(true, false, false)

val result = list.fold(initial = true) { accumulator, nextItem ->
    accumulator && nextItem
}
```

alternatively you can just check if list contains even one false using:

```
val result = (false !in list)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
val list = mutableListOf(true, false, false)

val allTrue = list.all { it }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin 1.5 you can use [none](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/none.html):

```
fun main() {
    val listWithFalse = mutableListOf(true, false, false, true)
    val listAllTrue = mutableListOf(true, true, true, true)

    println(listWithFalse.none { !it }) // false
    println(listAllTrue.none { !it }) // true
}
```

Comment: Using `list.all {it}` is cleaner as it doesn't require an extra negation